# How to inspect MetaMask

Tags: metamask, dapps, dapp-development, dapp-debugging, debugging

I was wondering how can I listen to the requests & data that are being sent between the MetaMask extension & DApp, My purpose is to inspect how is MetaMask reacting to DApp requests so that I can use these instructions in my development.

E.G: How does MetaMask react to `wallet_switchEthereumChain` request from DApp & what data is being communicated between two.